# Blinking Paren Mode

Tags: highlighting, balanced-parentheses, parentheses

I'm trying to get Paren Mode to be a little more clear, cause I can hardly see the other matching pair of parenthesis.

Is there any way I could make this blinking yellow?;)

I'm in gnome-terminal.

Here it says it can be blinking:

[Emacs Show Paren Mode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ShowParenMode)

```
To change the color/face:

    (require 'paren)
    (set-face-background 'show-paren-match (face-background 'default))
    (set-face-foreground 'show-paren-match "#def")
    (set-face-attribute 'show-paren-match nil :weight 'extra-bold)
```

Answer (score 0):

You pointed to a page that mentions option `blink-matching-paren`, but you apparently are not using it. Try using it: `M-x customize-option blink-matching-paren`.

`C-h v blink-matching-paren` tells you:

> `blink-matching-paren` is a variable defined in `simple.el`.
>
> Its value is `t`
>
> Documentation:
>
> Non-`nil` means show matching open-paren when close-paren is inserted.
>
> If `t`, highlight the paren.  If `jump`, briefly move cursor to its
> position.  If `jump-offscreen`, move cursor there even if the
> position is off screen.  With any other non-`nil` value, the
> off-screen position of the opening paren will be shown in the
> echo area.
>
> You can customize this variable.